# crash Console Application

Tags: c#, console-application

This is my problem:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public abstract class EntityMember<T>
    {
        public T Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Int32EntityMember : EntityMember<int?>
    {
    }

    public class StringEntityMember : EntityMember<string>
    {
    }

    public class GuidEntityMember : EntityMember<Guid?>
    {
    }

    public class Entity 
    {
        public GuidEntityMember ApplicationId { get; private set; }
        public Int32EntityMember ConnectedCount { get; private set; }
        public GuidEntityMember MainApplicationId { get; private set; }
        public Int32EntityMember ProcessId { get; private set; }
        public StringEntityMember ProcessName { get; private set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Entity entity2 = new Entity();
            Guid empty = Guid.NewGuid();
            Guid applicationId = Guid.NewGuid();
            int Id = 10;
            string name = "koko";

            entity2.MainApplicationId.Value = new Guid?(empty);
            entity2.ApplicationId.Value = new Guid?(applicationId);
            entity2.ProcessId.Value = new int?(Id);
            entity2.ProcessName.Value = name;
            entity2.ConnectedCount.Value = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

The application has totally blocked on the line:

```
entity2.MainApplicationId. Value = new Guid? (empty);
```

Why?

Comment: What error (if any) are you seeing?

Comment: Koka, welcome to stackoverflow =) When you ask a question here it's always useful to show as much relevant information as possible, so the content of any exceptions you're seeing is useful as well as your code =) If one of our answers solves your problem, please click on the outline of a tick next to the answer to mark it as your "accepted answer". Making sure you do this makes people more inclined to answer any future questions you ask here =) (*Edit: Which I can see you've just done!*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception you're receiving is:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is because `entity2.MainApplicationId` is null. Your `Entity` class does not have a constructor to set `MainApplicationId` to be not null, hence the error you're seeing.

Adding a constructor to your `Entity` class as shown in the code below results in your code running without error:

```
public Entity()
{
    ApplicationId = new GuidEntityMember();
    ConnectedCount = new Int32EntityMember();
    MainApplicationId = new GuidEntityMember();
    ProcessId = new Int32EntityMember();
    ProcessName = new StringEntityMember();
}
```

Using [Auto-Implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) does not result in the underlying fields (that are created and managed on your behalf by the compiler) being `new`'d when the instance is constructed. Thus the two properties that follow are **not** the same:

```
public MyClass MyProperty { get; private set; }

private MyClass _myOtherProperty = new MyClass();
public MyClass MyOtherProperty
{
    get
    {
        return _myOtherProperty;
    }
    set
    {
        _myOtherProperty = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: In fact all the fields of `entity2` are null

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
But for the getter and setter I think that two is the same, 

public MyClass myProperty (get; set;)

private MyClass = new MyClass _myOtherProperty ();
public MyClass MyOtherProperty
(
    get
    (
        _myOtherProperty return;
    )
    together
    (
        _myOtherProperty = value;
    )
)

Comment: @Koka, the two are clearly *not* the same, as I've explained in the answer, because in the first "auto-property", the backing field doesn't get an instance of `MyClass` new'd up, whereas in the second example, it does.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line to a type cast:

```
entity2.ApplicationId.Value = (Guid?)(applicationId);
```